# Wrap and unwrap XML with SOAP envelope in Java 1.5

Tags: java, xml, soap, java-5

I have an XML document as a string which is a SOAP request without the SOAP envelope. I now need to do the following:

- Post the request to a web service wrapped in a SOAP envelope
- Return the response with its SOAP envelope unwrapped

The actual HTTP connection stuff is fine, but I'm really struggling with the wrapping and unwrapping. I've tried to figure out how to do this XML manipulation in Java, but can't really figure it out. Looked at the `javax.xml` pacakge for example, but find most it to just be an enormous mess. I'm unfortunately limited to Java 1.5 and no external libraries, otherwise I'd probably used some apache commons stuff or something.

Basically what I'm looking for is a pair of methods like this:

```
/* Wraps the xml in a standard soap envelope */
String wrap(String xml)

/* Removes soap envelope from the xml */
String unwrap(String xml)
```

The `wrap` method I suppose could be as simple as `soapStart + xml + soapEnd`, although the xml header could mess things up if not careful. But the unwrapping gets too tricky for me as you need to actually extract what's in the `<soapenv:Body>` *and* make sure you get needed namespace declarations and such with you.

I've been sitting here for hours and I still have no idea... hopefully some of you guys do :)

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP part of the message contains an envelope that contains a body (which can contain data or fault information) and an optional header. When you use JAXM to create a SOAP message, the SOAP part, envelope, and body are created for you: you need only create the body elements. To do that you need to get to the parent of the body element, the SOAP body.

In order to reach any object in the SOAPMessage tree, you must traverse the tree starting from the root, as shown in the following lines of code. For example, assuming the SOAPMessage is MyMsg, here are the calls you would have to make in order to get the SOAP body:

```
SOAPPart MyPart = MyMsg.getSOAPPart();

SOAPEnvelope MyEnv = MyPart.getEnvelope();

SOAPBody MyBody = envelope.getBody();
```

At this point, you can create a name for a body element (as described in Namespaces) and add the body element to the SOAPMessage.

For example, the following code line creates a name (a representation of an XML tag) for a body element:

```
Name bodyName = envelope.createName("Temperature");
```

The next code line adds the body element to the body:

```
SOAPBodyElement myTemp = MyBody.addBodyElement(bodyName);
```

Finally, this code line defines some data for the body element bodyName:

```
myTemp.addTextNode("98.6");
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19263-01/817-6026/SOAP.html

Comment: What do I import to get access to these SOAP classes?

Comment: I believe they are part of Java 6 SE java.xml.soap package

Comment: Ah... I'm limited to Java 5 :/

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use regexes.
To find envelope content:

```
String regex = "^<(soapenv:Envelope).*?>(.*?)</\\1>$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);
matcher.matches();
String body = matcher.group(2);
```

Something like this

Comment: Yeah, thought about that and it would probably have worked if it wasn't for the namespaces.

Comment: If I understand You, You may try more complex regexp:
String regex = "^<([a-zA-Z0-9:]*)[^>\"]*+(?:\"[^\"]*+\"[^>\"]*+)*+>(.*?)</\\1>$" to extract content of enclosing element